# how to get a character from stdin without waiting for user to put it?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm writing a C program that prints something on terminal using ncurses. It should stop printing when user press 's' and continue again when press 's'. How can I read a key from input without waiting user to press the key?

I tried `getch()` and `getchar()` but they wait until a key is pressed...

**Edit**

This is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
   initscr(); /* Start curses mode         */
   refresh(); /* Print it on to the real screen */
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   int state = 0;
   while (1)
   {
      cbreak();
      int c = getch(); /* Wait for user input */
      switch (c)
      {
         case 'q':
            endwin();
            return 0;
         case 'c':
            state = 1;
            break;
         case 's':
            state = 0;
            break;
         default:
            state = 1;
            break;
      }
      if(state)
      {
         move(i, j);
         i++;
         j++;
         printf("a");
         refresh();
      }
   }
   nocbreak();
   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
This works well. I got 100 points :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{
   initscr();
   noecho();
   cbreak();         // don't interrupt for user input
   timeout(500);     // wait 500ms for key press
   int c = 0;        // command: [c|q|s]
   int s = 1;        // state: 1= print, 0= don't print ;-)
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (c != 'q')
   {
      int c = getch();
      switch (c)
      {
         case 'q':
            endwin();
            return 0;
         case 'c':
            s = 1;
            break;
         case 's':
            s = 0;
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
      if (s)
      {
         move(i, j);
         printw("a");
         i++;
         j++;
      }
   }
   endwin();
   nocbreak();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @FailedDev : I saw programs doing something like this... for example the tennis game moves the pad only when arrow keys one of right or left arrow keys is presses...

Comment: You don't want to use `printf("a")` in a curses program.  curses won't be aware that you've written anything.  It probably won't erase the `a` character, because it doesn't know it needs to, but you really want to use the appropriate curses function to write `"a"` into the current window, not to stdout.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Ok, I replaced `printf` with `printw`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ncurses has the capability to do this through it's own getch() function.  See [this](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_getch.3.asp) page

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {
  initscr();
  timeout(-1);
  int c = getch();
  endwin();
  printf ("%d %c\n", c, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any elucidation of what failed?  Or shall we just guess?  Your question is not clear. In one part you want to do something when a key is pressed; later, you want it to return whether a key is pressed or not.  What is the real need?

Comment: I want this: print `a` when idle (always), stop printing `a` when `s` is pressed, continue printing `a` when c pressed. exit program when `q` pressed.

Comment: sorry, not going to do all that work (note that all the modifications to your code were done after I answered the original question).  look at how to setup ncurses so that it returns immediately - timeout() - when no character is there and then test the return value to see if a valid character was input.

Comment: Thank you. It works with few changes. just timeout(500) and noecho().

Comment: @downvoter - I think maybe if you don't like the answer you should say why - no comment, no down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ncurses, you start by calling `cbreak` to turn off line buffering. Then you'll call `nodelay` to tell it not to wait before returning -- `getch` will always return immediately. When it does, you'll check whether a key was pressed, and if so what key that was (and react appropriately).

Comment: `timeout` sets the timeout for interpreting multibyte function key codes, and does not cause the `getch` call to return if no key has been pressed.  You want `nodelay`

Answer (score -1):

There's an answer to this in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com). See question 19.1, "How can I read a single character from the keyboard without waiting for the RETURN key? How can I stop characters from being echoed on the screen as they're typed?".

It's a bit long to post here.

Comment: seems strange since curses is not part of 'standard' C

Comment: @KevinDTimm: That's why it's in the "System dependencies" section.  It is a frequently asked question, after all; the answer happens to be along the lines of "You can't do that in standard C, but here's how you can do it on systems X and Y".

Comment: only strange as I just remember the responses from the comp.lang.c newsgroup regulars when someone would ask about items outside the standard - "You're in the wrong place, there is no <insert name of non-standard functionality here> in the standard"